# Ubuntu 20.04 keyboard and mouse starts to work only after a long while after boot

Tags: boot, 20.04, nvidia, keyboard, mouse

Weird problems. I started my Ubuntu 20.04 machine today after having done nothing special last time I shut it down. First it greeted me with the bare minimum resolution 800*600 and nothing else selectable. Then I reinstalled the Nvidia drivers and full resolution came back.

Strange thing however, is that after booting, first I get to a black screen with a mouse pointer I can't move for quite a while. Then I proceed on to the ordinary login screen with neither mouse nor keyboard still working (they worked before the black screen because I was able to chose to boot Ubuntu instead of Windows on my dual-boot machine). I wait a full minute or so, then suddenly my keyboard lights up and my mouse also starts working and I can login in and it is business as usual. What the heck is going on? Anyone?

Comment: check `dmesg` for  possible driver problems. Also strange that your nvidia drivers went "away". Might be a problem with your disk?

Comment: Yes it's weird. I did actually replace an old hard drive with a new one  the other day, but it isn't the one with Ubuntu on it. . New one seems to work but... To much power? Data loss? Seems that PSU should be handle a hard drive.